# Win32 Api tooltip from mouse position

Tags: python, winapi, tooltip, mousehover

**Environment:** I'm using python 2.7 wit win32api to do some windows automations. I'm currently trying to automate *updating* an antivirus and using it to scan the computer. The antivirus I'm currently working with for testing purpose is ESET Smart Security 6.

**Scenario:** Once I open the window of ESET there's a menu on the left side (which I can get the handle of) but then this menu has no *items* and no *children* (using SPY++) so I'm assuming the developers are just using a bitmap for their buttons and here's no actual controls or windows to send messages to (i noticed that also from Spy++ when I was listening to messages).

**Question:** The only way I thought of to click a button in that menu is to navigate the mouse across the menu and get the **tooltip** at each position until the wanted button is found then click the button. Example:  when the mouse is over the update button the tooltip that comes up is 'Virus signature database update'. I wanna try to do something like this:

```
def clickEsetMenuItem(text):
    found = 0         
    setCursorToTopOfMenu() # by getting the rect and doing some simple math
    while(!found)
        navigateCursorDown() # increment the y value of the cursor using SetCursorPos
        tooltip = getTooltipFromMousePos() #THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP            
        if(text in tooltip):
            found = 1
            click() # click here
    return
```

So I would call:

```
clickEsetMenuItem('database update')
```

**Summary** The above is just an idea of what I wanna do with some explanation of my scenario, bottom line is I want to get the tooltip from the current mouse position using win32 api, any ideas on how to do this? I know that a tooltip is part of the "tooltips_class32" class but how to get it from the current mouse position is the question.

Comment: What is `tooltip`? Text, an image? Is it important to match the tooltips with your language or is it enough to compare them for equality?

Comment: a [tooltip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760246(v=vs.85).aspx) is a control in windows, you can retrieve a handle to it and  it should have a text (which is what I'm trying to retrieve). what I want to compare is the text of the tooltip with the text I want.